# Powershell New-Service With User Credentials

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to add a service to my windows computer by using the command

```
New-Service -Name TestWorkerService -BinaryPath "C:\Test\TestingService\Service.exe" -Credential "" -Description "Testing Service" -DisplayName "Testing Service" -StartupType Automatic
```

(yes, I know I have `-Credential` set as "")

I am not sure what value should go for `-Credential`  I have tried just the `username` i've input into Powershell `$env:computername` and `$env:UserName` and I've used for `-Credential` the value I get from both of the above commands and added a "" between them, but I keep getting the error of

```
Can not be created due to the following error: The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name spsecified
```

What is the proper format the `New-Service` is expecting `-Credential` in?

**EDIT**
I tried to manually set it up, but I get the errors below.  These are the commands I used (pressing enter after each line)

```
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
$securepassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCrednetial ($username, $securepassword)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs an object of type [PSCredential](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential). It can be created manually using the command `Get-Credential`.

There are other ways, but they are a bit tricky because the password needs to be passed in as a [SecureString](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring).

You can find how to programmatically build a PSCredential object [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/add-credentials-to-powershell-functions).

---

Sample code:

```
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
$securepassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $securepassword)

New-Service [...] -Credential $cred
```

Comment: Part of what is mind boggling me is if I execute ``Get-Credential`` and input ``username`` and ``password`` everything connects as expected.  But with my script above if I only use ``username`` it gives the error

Comment: I guess a better way to phrase my question is, what format does ``username`` need to be in to work in my connection string above?  Or what other option(s) do I have to pass in a username/password to the code so that the service can run automatic

Comment: Please read the articles I linked. The problem is not in the username. Storing the password in a `PSCredential` object is a lot more complex than one would expect. If you run `Get-Credential` this is completely bypassed, but in order to do it programmatically you have to do more work.

Comment: Added sample code.

Comment: I've been trying this using Powershell Desktop App opened with Run as Admin.  Following your script, I get to the line ``$cred`` and when I hit return on it, I get the error ``New-Object: Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" arguments.  Can not process argument because the value of argument "password" is null.  But I just set it 2 lines up?

Comment: Typo. You wrote `$seceurepassword` instead of `$securepassword`.

Comment: using ``-Credential $cred`` I get an error of ``can not be created due to the following error: The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified`` - but that is the username and password I log into the computer with

Comment: Is it a domain user? Then you need to use the syntax `DOMAIN\username`.

Comment: I'm going to sound dumb for a moment, but when I look at ``User Accounts`` the ``Domain`` is not listed as the Computer Name, but the Company Name....that would be a ``Domain`` account, correct?

Comment: Very likely. Check your `USERDOMAIN` variable.

Comment: and use the value of ``$env:UserDomain\`` username?

Comment: Yes. You really should not run services under your user account, but if you want to do that and it's a domain account, you need to specify the full logon name including the domain.

Comment: it's a service account set-up to do this, not my user account :) -- when I open ``services.sc`` and right click to start the service I get the error ``Windows could not start the service on Local computer.  Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.``

Comment: This is a completely different issue and it's unrelated to using PowerShell to set up the service. If you have finally been able to pass the credentials to `New-Service`, please mark this question as answered and ask another one.